# To highlight the data acording with specific color in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I have a database in MySQL using Php. I fetch it and display it in table form.

I was trying to highlight the data with specific color with two conditions:

**Condition 1**:- whose age is grater than 24 (color is #FF7676) red

**Condition 2:**- whose age less than 20 (color is #F8FF00) Yellow

but when my all data is in yellow color

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>DataBase of Age</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.1-dist/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.1-dist/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.1-dist/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <style>
        .grater
        {
            background-color:#FF7676;
        }
        .small
        {
            background-color:#F8FF00;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>#</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td>City</td>
            <td>Post</td>
            <td>Salary</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $connection=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','db_employee') or die(mysqli_connect_error());
        echo"DataBase Connection Establish Successfully...!!!";
        $q=mysqli_query($connection,'select * from tbl_information');
        echo"Total number of record found are:-".mysqli_num_rows($q);
        $age=1;
        while($table=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
        {
            extract($table);
            $class=null;
            if($age>24)
            {
                $class='grater';
            }
            if($age<20)
            {
                $class='small';
            }
            $age++;
        ?>
        <tr class="<?=$class?>">
            <td><?=$emp_id?></td>
            <td><?=$emp_name?></td>
            <td><?=$emp_age?></td>
            <td><?=$emp_city?></td>
            <td><?=$emp_post?></td>
            <td><?=$emp_salary?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>
</body>
```

Please help me the code is not working.

Comment: You set `$age=1;` and then do nothing else with it except plus 1 each time. How many results are there because if there's less than 20, they'll all be yellow!

Comment: You're checking `$age` not `$emp_age`, at the moment it will only output `grater` on the `25th` row of the table, instead of the actual age value in the row.

Comment: you need to compare `$emp_age`, not `$age`

Comment: change `if($age>24)` to `if($emp_age>24)` and `if($age<20)` to `if($emp_age<20)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($age>24)
{
   $class='grater';
}
if($age<20)
{
   $class='small';
}
```

It will be

```
if($emp_age>24)
{
   $class='grater';
}
else if($emp_age<20)
{
  $class='small';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Explanations and Solution

**Explanation:** You  need to check the condition based on the variable name that you are printing in the loop.

You are printing the `$emp_age` and checking the condition based on the `$age` which seems to be mistake you have done.

**Note:** Why the need of `$age++` at the end. That can be removed.

If and else is enough no need to check again with else if.

The loop should be as follows.

```
if($emp_age>24)
{
   $class='grater';
}
else
{
  $class='small';
}
```

And your while loop will look like as follows.

**Solution:**

```
while($table=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
{
   extract($table);
   $class=null;
   if($emp_age>24)
   {
     $class='grater';
   }
   else
   {
     $class='small';
   }            
   ?>
   <tr class="<?=$class?>">
     <td><?=$emp_id?></td>
     <td><?=$emp_name?></td>
     <td><?=$emp_age?></td>
     <td><?=$emp_city?></td>
     <td><?=$emp_post?></td>
     <td><?=$emp_salary?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Its my pleasure :)